# json - how to get json to array

Tags: json, jq

I ran an `aws` command and the results as below:

```
[root@webserver-02 test]# aws ec2 describe-volumes --volume-ids vol-0be41aaca50a1d4d2 --profile donald 2> /dev/null|
jq -r '.Volumes[]|{"Tags":(.Tags | map({(.key//.Key): (.value//.Value)}) | add), VolumeId:.VolumeId,SnapshotId:.SnapshotId, Volumesize:.Size, CreateTime:.CreateTime, State:.State,"Instances": [.Attachments[0].InstanceId] }'
```

and the results as below:

```
{
  "Tags": {
    "Name": "4d2",
    "c": "c",
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b"
  },
  "VolumeId": "vol-0be41aaca50a1d4d2",
  "SnapshotId": "snap-0be43cb27ae60c978",
  "Volumesize": 8,
  "CreateTime": "2018-09-20T02:24:21.067Z",
  "State": "in-use",
  "InstanceId": "i-016c1d0448d6917f6"
}
```

OK. I want to display **InstanceId** json as follows:

```
{
    "Tags": {
        "Name": "4d2",
        "c": "c",
        "a": "a",
        "b": "b"
    },
    "VolumeId": "vol-0be41aaca50a1d4d2",
    "SnapshotId": "snap-0be43cb27ae60c978",
    "Volumesize": 8,
    "CreateTime": "2018-09-20T02:24:21.067Z",
    "State": "in-use",
    "Instances": [{
        "InstanceId": "i-016c1d0448d6917f6"
    }]
}
```

I am using `jq` in the `bash` shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this jq filter:

```
jq '.+{"Instances":[{InstanceId}]}|del(.InstanceId)' file
```

This adds the object `Instances` to the current JSON data using the value of `InstanceId`.
Then it deletes the `InstanceId` on the object root.